# QueryPath (PHP) and meta tags

Tags: php, meta, querypath

Does anyone have any examples of how to scrape meta tags using QueryPath? I'm trying to get the content of the following:

`<meta content="London" property="og:locality">`

I recently switched from simple_html_dom which was easy to use, well documented BUT slow. In comparison QueryPath is faster, but has crap documentation and very few questions on Google / SO.

Comment: So...by crap documentation, I'm guessing you've already looked at http://api.querypath.org/docs/ yes?

EDIT: Here are some examples that may be helpful: http://api.querypath.org/docs/_c_s_s_reference.html

Comment: Yes I've been through all those docs. Aside from the couple of examples on the other page you linked, none of the functions show examples or have any meaningful text unless you already know what you are looking for. For someone trying to get to grips with DOM selectoion as a whole it's pretty useless IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
$locality = qp($html)->find('meta[property="og:locality"]')->attr("content");
```

Where `$html` is the html page you want to parse. `$locality` would have the value `London` based on your given example.

Here's a good general tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-php-querypath/index.html